# Using Postman with Firebase Cloud Messaging to send a push notification to a specific iOS device

Tags: ios, firebase, apple-push-notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm trying to send a push notification to a specific iOS device using Postman as a trigger to send a request to Firebase Cloud Messaging.

As a response I get an error saying that I have an invalid APNS credential (InvalidApnsCredential). What am I doing wrong?

The url I'm sending the request to is:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
```

The request headers look like this:

```
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: key=[SERVER_KEY]
```

[SERVER_KEY] is the server key I took from the Firebase console project settings.

The body of the request:

```
{
    "to": "[REFRESH_TOKEN]",
    "notification": {
        "body": "Test body",
        "title": "Test title",
        "content_available": true,
        "priority": "high"
    }
}
```

Where [REFRESH_TOKEN] is the refresh token I extract from the FIRInstanceID:

```
NSString *token = [[FIRInstanceID instanceID] token];
```

The full actual response that is returned:

```
{
    "multicast_id": XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX,
    "success": 0,
    "failure": 1,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "error": "InvalidApnsCredential"
        }
    ]
}
```

The multicast_id is some number I just covered up.

I issued fresh production and development certificates and added them to the Firebase console, still the same error. Also, tried with APNs Authentication Key, but to no avail.

Comment: Are you unable to send a notification via the console as well?

Comment: It doesn't work through the console either. I tired both updating the APNs Authentication Key and with APNs Certificates.

Comment: Is there any news, i'm facing this right now...